# Counting votes: How many possible paths exist on which candidate A is never 2 votes ahead

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, binomial-coefficients, solution-verification

This question is inspired by [Bertrand's ballot theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem). I want to check if I have understood the counting method correctly. I changed the initial problem of the ballot theorem a little bit.

> Suppose we have two candidates, A and B. After having counted the votes we have a tie. How many paths exist on which candidate A is never $\geq2$ votes ahead?

This is my approach:

I envision the election as a path on the $x$-axis which starts at $(0, 0)$ and ends at $(2p, 0)$, where $2p$ denotes the total number of votes. In the proof of the *ballot-theorem* they use a second path which is constructed by partly reflecting the original paths over the $x$-axis. I will try to follow this idea.

Firstly, I shift the start of all my paths to $(-2,2)$ and the first two votes must always be in favor of B. Secondly, I will extend the path until $(2p+2, 2)$ wheras the last two votes will count for A. Out of those paths I will only consider those ones which start with two consecutive votes for B and end with two consecutive votes for A (otherwise we would include paths that are definitively not allowed). Let's denote $M$ as the set of those paths. Hence, $|M|={2p \choose p}$.

Then I construct *auxiliary* paths as follows:

Let be $P$ a path of $M$. As long as $P$ doesn't touch the horizontal line which goes through $(0,2)$ (see red line in the picture) I reflect its values over the horizontal line which goes through $(0,2)$. Those values are the first points of the *auxiliary* paths. When $P$ touches the $(0,2)$-line the *auxiliary* paths will follow the rest of $P$. The construction of those *auxiliary* paths is a bijection into the set of those paths of $M$ which touch or cross the $(0, 2)$ line. So I simply have to subtract all *auxiliary* paths from $|M|$.

[image: _auxiliary path_]

Now I count all the *auxiliary* paths (I will do this in a bit more detail):

I have added $4$ votes to the $2p$ votes from the beginning (see green lines). $4$ votes of every *auxiliary* path are always the same meaning that the first two votes and the last two votes always count for A. Hence, all *auxiliary* paths sum up to: ${2p \choose p-2}$. The total number of paths where A is never $\geq 2$ votes ahead is ${2p \choose p}-{2p \choose p-2}=\frac{4p+2}{(p+1)(p+2)}{2p \choose p}$.

Is this correct?

I appreciate any comment or suggestion and please let me know if I should be clearer in any step.

Comment: The formula $\binom{2p}p-\binom{2p}{p-2}$ is correct, but it shuold instead simplify to $\frac{4p+2}{(p+1)(p+2)}\binom{2p}p$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest, thank you. I have edited this.

Comment: @MikeEarnest, can you explain it why I have to add two opposite edges at the end of the  _auxiliary_ paths? Why is it wrong if I simply add two edges at the beginning?

Comment: I do not know about your solution which involves adding edges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the correct answer, but there is a simpler explanation which does not require augmenting paths. We are counting paths from $(0,0)$ to $(2p,0)$ whose steps are all of the form $(1,\pm 1)$, and whose $y$ coordinate is never equal to $-2$. We take all $\binom{2p}p$ paths, and subtract the bad paths which at some point hit $y=-2$. If we reflect such a bad path after the first time it hits $y=-2$, we end up with an arbitrary path to $(2p,-4)$. Therefore, the number of bad paths is the number of paths to $(2p,-4)$, which is $\binom{2p}{p-2}$.